# Shortcut in Rubymine for switching from method call to definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shortcut, rubymine

Suppose I have a method in VIEW called `my_method()` and it is defined in application_helper.rb. I want to know the shortcut for switching  from `my_method()` call in VIEW to its definition in application_helper.rb.

I am using windows 7 and Rubymine 5.

Comment: Can you show some code where you've tried, and show what you're expected out come is?

Comment: You can just Ctrl+Click it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Navigate` | `Declaration`, shortcut would depend on your keymap, you can view it here:

[image: Declaration]

Default keymap uses these:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>
- <kbd>Right Click</kbd>